# How to identify what outdoor pipe is for sprinkler system?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, landscaping, sprinkler-system

I am planning to add a shut off valve from a hose bib to the sprinkler system.  I am having some difficulty identifying what the pipe to the left (image below) is or what it does!

Seems random - but since this house is 50+ years old, nothing surprises me and I don’t want to tear something out or cap it off if it’s required in the outdoor plumbing somehow.

Anyone recognize what that is?

[image: Random Sprinkler pipe]

Comment: Looks like an old raised sprinkler head to me, if so, there was likely a bush there when it was installed, and it may have a single screw on the top to adjust flow and it may be completely turned off via that.

Comment: What is the pipe material? I can't tell. If copper I don't think it was original , if galvanized it could be from that era, but have not seen anything like this in the past. Where in the world are you, is this pipe capped? If so it is possibly a way to eliminate water hammer if either galvanized or copper many systems we installed back in the 70's used a long dead head pipe to eliminate water hammer this would be my best guess with the info and photo.